# What are the differences between `-d` and `-D` when deleting a branch in git?

Tags: git

The following two git commands can both delete a branch,

```
git branch -d branchname
```

and

```
git branch -D branchname
```

What are the differences between `-d` and `-D` then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From the `git-branch` manual:

```
-d, --delete
       Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in HEAD if no upstream was set with --track or --set-upstream.

   -D
       Shortcut for --delete --force.
```

So `-D` forces the branch delete, which can be used if the branch is not merged into its upstream branch. Otherwise, using `git branch -d` on an unmerged branch will fail.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does "the upstream branch" of a branch mean its parent branch, i.e. the branch from which it was created? (2)  If a branch is merged into another branch which is not its upstream branch, can `git branch -d` still work?

Comment: @Tim I believe it could be any branch. upstream/downstream is defined by humans within the project, not by the tool. So yes, I believe the -d option will work as long as it's contents is merged into another branch.

Comment: @einonm the branch deletion behaviour is fully defined in the documentation you quote: the deleted branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in HEAD if it doesn’t have an upstream branch. Other branches don’t count. Upstream does have a meaning for git.